# Accessing the inner most value of json through java

Tags: java, json, gson

I have the below JSON string from which I am trying to access the value of authenticators but I am not successful in accessing the tag values, I am using GSON library for parsing as I have separate POJO for authenticators which I am trying to map, please advise how can I access the authenticator's tag value

```
{
  "peopleName": "string",
  "peopleCode": "string",
  "username": "string",
  "businessName": "string",
  "businessEmail": "string",
  "contactNumber": "string",
  "authenticators": [
    {
      "name": "ABC",
      "connectorType": "com.abc.ert",
      "connectorProperties": {
        "url": "http://res:8087/ert",
        "connectionTimeout": "80s",
        "readTimeout": "57s"
      }
    }
  ],
```

Comment: Please, send your code that trying to access the value.

Answer (score 0):

`Authenticators` tag can be accessed by introducing a `POJO` that wraps the `json string`, Since the `authenticators` is a `json array` it has to be represented as an `array` or `list`

```
public class JsonObject {

    //Your Authenticator POJO
    private List<Authenticator> authenticators;

    public List<Authenticator> getAuthenticators() {
        return authenticators;
    }

    public void setAuthenticators(List<Authenticator> authenticators) {
        this.authenticators = authenticators;
    }
}
```

Now the `json string` can be mapped to `POJO` using `Gson`

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonObject jsonObject = gson.fromJson("json string", JsonObject.class);
// Access the name of the first `authenticator`
System.out.println(jsonObject.getAuthenticators().get(0).getName());
```